# Making list item unselectable

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with my custom content. I have on message iamgeview, one call and other option. So that user can select any one of the option, but if user select any text(touch the textview) or any other portion of ListView, it should not respond. I have small UI.

So if user touches on MyText, nothing should be  done. Not even Visual feed back what we get when we touch list tiem normally in android. But touch event for call, or message should come.

My code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_contact"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_textmessage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

PS: On touching the portion of textview, by default first ImageView is getting selected. I don't want that any wodget should respond unless touched

Comment: give action for the image views that u have and wont give action for list view onitem click so it is not going to do anything if u select the text view

Comment: "On touching the portion of textview, by default first ImageView is getting selected. " how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The visual feedback on touching an item  is a style on the ListView. You can change it as below:

```
<ListView 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

However, it's best to [define your own styles and apply them](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to the views.